# MVVM – First Application in TutorialPoint Type 'MVVM.Views.StudentView' is not defined

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I am beginner in MVVM and WPF
Iam Using VB.NET 2015
I try the tutorial in [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm) and the code in C# while iam use vb.net, i use **telerik** to convert from c# to vb. I did everything as in this tutorial. But I'm still getting an exception:

> BC3002:
>   Type 'BillingBersama.BillingBersama.Views.StudentView' is not defined .. MainWindow.xaml    67

The line error, MainWindow.xaml:

```
<views:StudentView x:Name="StudentViewControl" Loaded="StudentViewControl_Loaded" />
```

here the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My8VG.png)

**StudentModel.vb**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Namespace MVVMDemo.Model
    Public Class StudentModel
    End Class

    Public Class Student
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Private m_firstName As String
        Private m_lastName As String

        Public Property FirstName() As String
            Get
                Return m_firstName
            End Get

            Set
                If m_firstName <> Value Then
                    m_firstName = Value
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName")
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property LastName() As String
            Get
                Return m_lastName
            End Get

            Set
                If m_lastName <> Value Then
                    m_lastName = Value
                    RaisePropertyChanged("LastName")
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property FullName() As String
            Get
                Return Convert.ToString(m_firstName & Convert.ToString(" ")) & m_lastName
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler
        Private Event INotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged([property] As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs([property]))
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**StudentViewModel.vb**

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports MVVMDemo.MVVMDemo.Model

Namespace MVVMDemo.ViewModel

    Public Class StudentViewModel
        Private Student As Object
        Public Property Students() As ObservableCollection(Of Student)
            Get
                Return m_Students
            End Get
            Set
                m_Students = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Students As ObservableCollection(Of Student)

        Public Sub LoadStudents()
            Dim students__1 As New ObservableCollection(Of Student)()

            students__1.Add(New Student() With {
                .FirstName = "Mark",
                .LastName = "Allain"
            })
            students__1.Add(New Student() With {
                .FirstName = "Allen",
                .LastName = "Brown"
            })
            students__1.Add(New Student() With {
                .FirstName = "Linda",
                .LastName = "Hamerski"
            })

            Students = students__1
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**StudentView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMDemo.Views.StudentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo.MVVMDemo.Views" 

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment = "Left">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Students}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = FirstName, Mode = TwoWay}" 
                        Width = "100" Margin = "3 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = LastName, Mode = TwoWay}" 
                        Width = "100" Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = FullName, Mode = OneWay}" 
                        Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
        xmlns:views ="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo.MVVMDemo.Views"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--<views:StudentView x:Name = "StudentViewControl" Loaded = "StudentViewControl_Loaded"/>-->
        <!--this line is the error-->
        <views:StudentView x:Name="StudentViewControl" Loaded="StudentViewControl_Loaded" />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.vb**

```
Namespace MVVMDemo
    Partial Public Class MainWindow


        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        Private Sub StudentViewControl_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Dim studentViewModelObject As New ViewModel.StudentViewModel()
            studentViewModelObject.LoadStudents()

            'this Line:  "StudentViewControl"  Is Error, copy from convert telerik
            'then I fix it from recomended VS Intellisense "Dim StudentViewControl As Object = Nothing"
            Dim StudentViewControl As Object = Nothing
            StudentViewControl.DataContext = studentViewModelObject
        End Sub


    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Application.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="MVVMDemo.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

So that's it. If somebody would me explain what's going on here? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Not enough info to tell.  Delete all bin/obj folders in the solution.  Restart visual studio. Rebuild all.  If that doesn't fix it, delete the StudentView and re-create it.  Don't copy over the generated root elements in XAML or the generated namespace and class name in the codebehind.

Comment: I have try to delete all in bin/obj/ excluded folder and try it to code from beginning, but I have the same error.

Comment: Hope the answer in this link might shed some light. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85091/error-bc30002-type-xxx-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but maybe someone else struggles too.

The problem is probably the namespace, ns definitions work a little different in vb compared to c#

As you can see in your StudentView.xaml you are importing

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel 
Imports MVVMDemo.MVVMDemo.Model
 
Namespace MVVMDemo.ViewModel
```

Note that MVVMDemo appears twice, while the namespace definition in your model only contains it once:

```
Namespace MVVMDemo.Model
```

The first originates from your project name, the second originates from your explicit namespace definition.

Since you didn't post your StudentView.xaml.vb i can only assume it contains

```
Namespace MVVMDemo.Views
```

This would require your StudentView.xaml to start like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMDemo.MVVMDemo.Views.StudentView"
```

The reason is that vb adds the projectname in front of your defined namespace by default. So you can also fix your project by removing MVVMDemo from your namespace definitions.